# Using composer-wallet-redis , where to see the card in redis service?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I follow the guideline .

- Install composer-wallet-redis image and start the container.
- export NODE_CONFIG={"composer":{"wallet":{"type":"@ampretia/composer-wallet-redis","desc":"Uses  a local redis instance","options":{}}}}
- composer card import admin@test-network.card

I found the card still store in my local machine at path ~/.composer/card/
How can I check whether the card exist in the redis server?

How to import the business network cards into the cloud custom wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue (which I will correct in the README) is that the module name should the `composer-wallet-redis`  The @ampretia was a temporary repo.

Assuming that redis is started on the default port, you can run the redis CLI like this

```
docker run -it --link composer-wallet-redis:redis --rm redis redis-cli -h redis -p 6379
```

You can then issue redis cli commands to look at the data. Though it is not recommended to view the data or modify it. Useful to confirm to yourself it's working.  The `KEYS *` command will display everything but this should only be used in a development context.  See the warnings on the redis docs pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. export NODE_ENVIRONMENT
2. start the docker container
3. composer card import
4. execute `docker run ***` command followed by `KEYS *` ,empty list or set.

@Calanais